# Using Karatsuba algorithm to multiply [Edit: Answered]

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, number-systems

I've been looking over this, and haven't seen anything wrong in my procedure.

### Take
2468
*3162

[Using Karatsuba multiplication]:

x=2468

y=3162

x={(a)24}{(b)68}

y={(c)31}{(d)62}

Step 1: a*c=(24)(31)=744

Step 2: b*d=(68)(62)=4216

Step 3:(24+68)(31+62)=8556

Step 4: 8556-4216-744=3596

Step 5:

7440000+4216+3596000=11,040,216

However 3162*2468=7,803,816

I've looked over this . I am using even digit numbers. Let me know what needs to be done to this to get the right answer.

Comment: You are supposed to add $744\cdot100^2+3596\cdot 100^1+4216$. In other words, there is one extra zero in $3596000$. Think base $100$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen okay this helped thanks.

Comment: @Tortar : If your comment answered the question, you should post an answer. In general, question-and-answer pages should be "self-contained" in that they should not require reading comments for essential information. On the other hand, if you think the answer is too trivial or this question is too trivial for an answer, you should vote to close this question.

Comment: @PeterO. Done. Check.